# What happens to the amplituhedron in a non-peturbative context?

Tags: string-theory, scattering, branes, non-perturbative, amplituhedron

The **[Amplituhedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/amplituhedron)** has recently been popular; it supposedly encodes  **perturbative scattering  amplitudes** in a simple, **geometric** fashion.

What happens to it in a **non-perturbative** context? Is there still some sort of amplituhedron, somehjow?

If so, a side question:

Can the amplitudihedron be able to solve the problem of 5-Brane scattering amplitudes in  M-Theory?

Comment: Regarding the M5-branes... It seems plausible that the worldvolume theory of a stack of M5-branes - which will be some version of (2,0) theory - has an amplituhedron, simply because (2,0) is another conformal, maximal-susy theory.

Comment: But that's the theory of scattering *inside* an M5-brane - how the excitations of the M5-brane interact. Scattering of M5-branes from each other, in some more general space-time background, is a different story, and ties into the general problem of how to understand string theory in the most general way possible.

Comment: The amplituhedron relies heavily on momentum twistors which only work for 4D theories. It may be possible to generalise in some way to higher dimensions but I think that would require a new idea.

Comment: You can define twistor space for six space-time dimensions e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2539, and there are many connections between 4d, 5d, and 6d SUSY QFTs, e.g. see Witten's work on Khovanov homology. So point taken, but there's reason to believe it's possible.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: no expert on this, but one of the lessons learned about the (2,0) theory is that it manifestly has no weak-coupling description. You need to be more precise about "scattering within a M5 brane", otherwise I have a hard time seeing how it's plausible that a "Grassmannian" description exists.

Comment: @Vibert Perhaps it would be the scattering of the tensionless strings? But both N=4 SYM, and ABJM, have Grassmannian descriptions, so it makes sense that (2,0) would, too.